# Why video of camera interference in android 2.3?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

```
public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
            if (c != null) {
                Camera.Parameters params = c.getParameters();
                params.setRotation(90);
                c.setParameters(params);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Camera did not open");
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)

        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }
```

onCreate:

```
// Create an instance of Camera
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.addView(mPreview);
```

CameraPreview:

```
public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }
```

I using MediaRecorder record video.
Result: 
[image]
if i test on device android 4.0, result is ok. but in android 2.3 it is interference 
Why  video of  camera interference in android 2.3?(Note: Capture Image , it is ok.)

Answer (score 1):

This is just one potential problem. From the docs:

```
// deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

You are not implementing the Camera API correctly. Please look at the [Android Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera) on how to create a camera app.

Comment: i had set in CameraPreview

Comment: Are you actually using the callbacks?

Comment: You are setting the callback, but are you using the callback's methods for anything?

Comment: I only init: mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera); and use mCamera.

Comment: That is what I mean by not using the API correctly. Look at the link and how they show to use the callback's methods

Comment: i'm sorry: i using for capture image: private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {....

Comment: As you said you are passing `this` when you register it. The picture callback is not what I mean. I am talking about the surface callbacks.

Comment: Can you say where i had error? if not use Callback ,  must i remove  mHolder.addCallback(this); ?

Comment: You do not have to remove it, you just need to implement its methods like it is done on the link I posted.